# Populate MS Word Merge Field records Programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, mailmerge

I am trying to load up Mail Merge recipients and their records dynamically in C# using [MailMerge interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.mailmerge). I managed to load up the header using [MailMerge.CreateDataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.mailmerge.createdatasource) method giving a comma separated string in HeaderRecord. These fields show up when I run Word but the problem is that I can't find any method to populate it's records as well. Currently how I am doing it is making the following csv file and using `MailMerge.OpenDataSource` method to load this datasource:

```
Name, Age, Gender, Country, Email
Dummy1, Male, 20, England, dummy1@gmail.com
Dummy2, Male, 21, Spain, dummy2@gmail.com
Dummy3, Male, 22, France, dummy3@gmail.com
```

My requirement is to load the data without creating any external file, I'm looking for something which would do something similar to:

```
MailMerge.AddRecord("Dummy1, Male, 20, England, dummy1@gmail.com")
```

Comment: I can't tell if this is the same question, but the discussion here may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843694/is-it-possible-to-write-a-word-add-in-or-something-similar-to-provide-a-custom-m/11854434#11854434

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to use fully managed .NET solution with OpenXML. Since OpenXML has steep learning curve, it would probably make sense to look for a toolkit which uses that kind of approach.

I have good experience with Docentric Toolkit. I have been using it for three years now. So here are its pros and cons:

Pros:

- plain simple Word Add-in for template generation
- OpenXML based, server side friendly
- support for images, data-bound graphs, tables
- conditional elements in templates support for placeholders in headers
  and footers
- very fast report generation

Cons:

- not free
- support for PDF output is still somewhat limited.

You can see [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/759408/Creating-Word-documents-in-Net-using-Docentric-Too) on Code Project to get first impression about using this toolkit for merging data (from XML, database, in-memory,...) with appropriate template.